# Searching for a post containing a query string , using graph API for iOS isn't working properly?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using graph API to search all the public posts, containing a specific string in post.
I used code described in Facebook SDK's documentation.

but instead of post data i am getting
the following

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

my code is as follows :-

```
NSString *client_id = @"426************" ;
fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGetSearchWithQuery:@"college" andObjectType:@"post"];
NSLog(@"GetSearchButtonPressed create Watch:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

**my output is :-**

2013-12-22 12:36:50.683 Appname[1029:c07] ACT isn't nill

2013-12-22 12:36:51.380 Appname[1029:c07] GetSearchButtonPressed create Watch:  {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}

**all used methods in above code are as follows :-**

```
- (FbGraphResponse *)doGraphGetSearchWithQuery:(NSString *)query andObjectType:(NSString *)objectType
{
    NSString *url_string;


    url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%@&type=%@",query,objectType];


if (accessToken != nil) {
    NSLog(@"ACT isn't nill");
    //now that any variables have been appended, let's attach the access token....
    url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@access_token=%@", url_string, self.accessToken];
}

//encode the string
url_string = [url_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return [self doGraphGetWithUrlString:url_string];  

}



- (FbGraphResponse *)doGraphGetWithUrlString:(NSString *)url_string {

FbGraphResponse *return_value = [[[FbGraphResponse alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *resp;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];

if (resp != nil) {

    /**
     * In the case we request a picture (avatar) the Graph API will return to us the actual image
     * bits versus a url to the image.....
     **/
    if ([resp.MIMEType isEqualToString:@"image/jpeg"]) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:response];
        return_value.imageResponse = image;

    } else {

        NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return_value.htmlResponse = stringResponse;
        [stringResponse release];           
    }

} else if (err != nil) {
    return_value.error = err;
}

return return_value;

}
```

I have used This as [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)

Comment: You have @"%@access_token=%@", but it should be @"%@&access_token=%@" (note the "&").

Comment: @MingLi : thanks .. that worked just fine... what a dumb i am...:D
well... anyways.. is there a way to obtain search for all the posts in a particular group whose group ID is provided...???